# How do I pass the elements of a Python list to HTML for different HREF links?

Tags: python, html, python-2.7

I have a list of filenames in Python, and I want to pass that to HTML. The HTML page should have different href links for each of the filenames in the list. If I pass the whole list then the href link is again a list (which does not allow me to click on different links), and if I use a for loop to pass the list elements one by one, it is getting displayed as different HTML pages.

EDIT: Here is my code. 'docs' is a list of filenames. This is printing "Results" followed by first link, then "Results" followed by second link, and so on. I want it to display "Results" and then all the links one below the other. Basically, I want the loop only for the 'a href' part.

```
def results(docs):
template = """
<html>
<head>
    <title> Results </title>
</head>
<body>
 <a href="file://%s"> %s </a>
</body>
</html>
"""

html = ""
for i in range(len(docs)):
    html = '\n'.join([html, template % (docs[i], docs[i])])

return html
```

PS: Sorry if the question is unclear, it is the first time I am posting a question on stackoverflow.

Comment: Show us your code. Are you using any template engines?

Comment: @alecxe : Added code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd actually use a *template engine*, like [`Mako`](http://www.makotemplates.org/). Working example:

```
from mako.template import Template

def results(docs):
    template = """
    <html>
    <head>
        <title> Results </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    % for doc in docs:
         <a href="file://${doc}"> ${doc} </a>
    % endfor
    </body>
    </html>
    """
    return Template(template).render(docs=docs)

print(results(["link1", "link2"]))
```

Prints:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Results </title>
</head>
<body>
     <a href="file://link1"> link1 </a>
     <a href="file://link2"> link2 </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using a template engine?

Comment: @VS17 sure, you can do it "manually" with `format()`, but, sorry, I just think template engine is the tool for the problem in this case.